# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.9d

Tags: compiling, make, libraries, cmake

I have this error on ubuntu 20.04 while running cmake then make

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable ./tmp/DearPyGuiDearSandbox/DearSandbox
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.9d
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [sandbox/CMakeFiles/DearSandbox.dir/build.make:102: ./tmp/DearPyGuiDearSandbox/DearSandbox] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:218: sandbox/CMakeFiles/DearSandbox.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I already tried to include them in the CMakeLists.txt but no luck

```
include_directories(/usr/include/python3.9)
include_directories(./miniconda3/envs/ngp/lib/python3.9/)
include_directories(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)
include_directories(/usr/share/doc/libpython3.9)
include_directories(/usr/share/doc/libpython3.9-dev
```

Comment: Do you have the libpython3.9-dbg package installed?

Comment: it fixed my problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify which package(s) contain(s) a missing file, install apt-file

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Then update the search database:

```
apt-file update
```

Then you may search for the file:

```
apt-file search libpython3.9d
```

Identifying the libpython3.9-dbg package, which you may then install.